# Código 401 al intentar leer el Stream de Twitter

Tags: python, twitter-api, tweepy

Estoy realizando una prueba con el Stream de Twitter y me devuelve Código 401, alguien sabe cual es el problema o que estoy haciendo mal porque la verdad ya he probado gran número de cosas y nada funciona a continuación dejo mi código, cualquier sugerencia sera agradecida.

```
import json
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

proxies = {
    'http': '127.0.0.1:3128',
    'https': '127.0.0.1:3128'
}
#### 23.055836, -82.528810
#### 23.0263076,-82.2068166

consumer_key = "XXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
access_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

file = open('tweets.txt', 'a')


class ProxyStream(Stream):

    def new_session(self):
        super().new_session()  # PY2: super(ProxyStream, self).new_session()
        self.session.proxies = {
            'http': '127.0.0.1:3128',
            'https': '127.0.0.1:3128'
        }


class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        # La API de Twitter devuelve datos en formato JSON, asi que hay que decodificarlos.
        try:
            decoded = json.loads(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print('----->', e)
        return True

        if decoded.get('geo') is not None:
            location = decoded.get('geo').get('coordinates')
        else:
            location = '[,]'
        text = decoded['text'].replace('\n', ' ')
        user = '@' + decoded.get('user').get('screen_name')
        created = decoded.get('created_at')
        tweet = '%s|%s|%s|s\n' % (user, location, created, text)

        file.write(tweet)
        print(tweet)
        return True

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not status.retweeted and 'RT @' not in status.text:
            try:
                tweet = status.extended_tweet['full_text']
            except AttributeError:
                tweet = status.text
            print(tweet)
        else:
            return

    # def on_exception(self, exception):
    #     print(exception)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print('----->', status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Empezando...')

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, proxy='127.0.0.1:3128')
twitterStream = ProxyStream(auth, listener(), async=True)
twitterStream.filter(track=["#Clima"])
```